# Can't find definition of model "SD210"

Tags: transistors, mosfet, ltspice, powermosfet

I am trying to simulate the attached circuit but LTSpice has been putting the message "Can't find definition of model "SD210".

[image]

The transistor are double diffused MOSFET and I took the model from the manufacturer (Linear circuit). Next I added the model directly in the .asc project using a non standard transistor (I don't know if it may cause a problem).

The model text is:

```spice
M1 drainin gatein N_0 SD210
.SUBCKT SD210 NMOS(Level=1 Cbd=8.08p Cbs=9.7p Cgbo=20.6n CGDO=2n Cgso=2.4n
+Gamma=.92 Is=0.325p Kp=4.5m Lambda=22m Mj=.46 Pb=.8 Phi=.75 Rd=8 Rs=13 Vto=1.1
+Mfg=Linear_Systems)
```

I tried to replace `SUBCKT` with `model` and it didn't work either. If you can help me I will be very grateful.

Comment: Perhaps you'll find your answer here: https://maker.pro/forums/threads/sd21x-spice-model.37727/

Answer (score 3):

@Velvel thank you for the [link](https://maker.pro/forums/threads/sd21x-spice-model.37727/). There I could learn more about my problem and the few reasons why I was getting it. I came up with this solution: I specified the size of my transistor and the final model is as follow below.

```spice
MN1 %d %g %s %b SD210 L=0.5u W=889u 
.MODEL SD210 NMOS Level=1 CBD=4.65P CBS=5.58P CGBO=20.6N
+ CGDO=2N CGSO=2.4N GAMMA=.992 IS=3.25E-13 KP=7.15M
+ LAMBDA=22.5M MJ=.46 PB=.8 PHI=.75 RD=12 RS=15 VTO=1.15
```

How to use?

- Import a NMOS generic transistor
- Make sure its prefixstarts with NM (moving the cursor on the body of the transistor and doing ctrl+right click in the dialog box that will show up)
- Change the Value in the dialog box to SD210

Comment: If you want to specify width and length, it’s better to use the `nmos4` symbol instead of using a line of code.